# Visual Studio 2017 installation stuck

Tags: macbook-pro, install

I'm trying to install visual studio 2017 on my macbook but the installer is stuck at "preparing to download". I have xcode installed and there is no error in the log:

```
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.634] [Info] Installation of software items is starting.
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.634] [Debug] Checking software item 'Mono Framework'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.634] [Info] Software item 'Mono Framework' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.634] [Debug] Checking software item 'Visual Studio'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.634] [Info] Software item 'Visual Studio' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.634] [Debug] Checking software item '.NET Core 2.x'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.635] [Info] Software item '.NET Core 2.x' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.635] [Debug] Checking software item 'Xamarin.Android'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.635] [Debug] Checking software item 'Xamarin.iOS'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.635] [Info] Software item 'Xamarin.iOS' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.635] [Debug] Checking software item 'Xamarin.Mac'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.635] [Info] Software item 'Xamarin.Mac' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.636] [Debug] Checking software item 'Xamarin Workbooks'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.636] [Info] Software item 'Xamarin Workbooks' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.636] [Debug] Checking software item 'Xamarin Profiler'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.636] [Info] Software item 'Xamarin Profiler' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.636] [Debug] Checking software item 'Mobile OpenJDK'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.636] [Info] Software item 'Mobile OpenJDK' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.637] [Debug] Checking software item 'Android SDK'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.637] [Debug] Checking software item 'Intel® HAXM'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.637] [Info] Software item 'Intel® HAXM' does not need to be installed
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.637] [Debug] Starting installation task.
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.637] [Info] Background installation worker called.
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.638] [Info] Processing software items
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.638] [Info] Skipping installation of software item 'Mono Framework'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.638] [Info] Skipping installation of software item 'Visual Studio'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.638] [Info] Skipping installation of software item '.NET Core 2.x'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.638] [Info] Installing software item 'Xamarin.Android'
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.638] [Debug] Starting Xcode detection
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.639] [Info] Xamarin.Android is waiting for download to finish.
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.841] [Debug] Detected the following Xcode versions
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.841] [Debug] /Applications/Xcode.app (version 11.3.1)
[2020-03-07 12:45:03.843] [Debug] Xcode is installed or not required - no need to remind.
```